# Make the table and figure caption in one document is align to colon (:) in greater or equal second line

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, captions, indentation

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption}
\captionsetup{
    indention=1.6cm
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}
        \caption{This is the example image. This is the example image. This is the example image. This is the example image.}
    \end{figure}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        No&Alphabet\\
        1&a\\
        2&b\\
        3&c\\
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{This is example of table. abcdefghijkl This is example of table. This is example of table. This is example of table. This is example of table. This is example of table.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I want to make figure and table caption in second line is align to colon (:), so I try to add

```
\captionsetup{
    indention=1.6cm
 }
```

[image]

But in the table caption second line cannot align to colon (:).

[image]

I think because I give the indention in `\captionsetup` is manually.
How to make automatic indent in greater than or equal second line align to colon (:) over a document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change

```
\captionsetup{indention=1.6cm}
```

to

```
\captionsetup{format=hang}
```